# Почему не работает регулярное выражение /[–-А]/?

Tags: javascript, node.js, регулярные-выражения, frontend

Я писал регулярное выражение, которое находит в строке символ, который является: длинным тире (–), обычным тире (-), или буквой 'А'.

Получился RegExp: `/[–-А]/`, но при его создании вылезает ошибка:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[–-А]/: Range out of order in character class
```

Если поменять тире местами - `/[-–А]/`, то выражение создаcтся без ошибок и будет корректно работать.

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему так получается? Почему `/[–-А]/` даёт синтаксическую ошибку, а `/[-–А]/` нормально работает?

Comment: минус - это диапазон символов, но если стоит первым или последним. то просто сам минус. Так что `А–-` тоже будет работать

Comment: Кстати, если бы вы написали наоборот `A-–` ошибки бы не было, поскольку A больше, чем тире

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Символ `-` (минус) в регулярных выражениях имеет специальное значение.

В первом случае он воспринимается как обычный символ, т.к. стоит первым, и выражение `/[-–А]/` означает искать один из трех символов.

Во втором выражении `/[–-А]/` он означает диапазон значений, т.к. стоит вторым, и это значит - искать все символы от `–` до `А`, что некорректно, т.к. `–` больше `А`.

То есть, для второго случая его надо экранировать так: `/[–\-А]/`.